# What to do when boss pays me only when there is work to be done?

Tags: salary

I started to work and at first was paid hourly. After training and some experience they said they would be putting me on piece work in that when a job comes in it is assessed and I am told I get paid "X" amount to complete the job, it sounded good while it was busy.

Early winter, snow cold and it almost stopped getting work. The boss still requires me to come in case some work shows up but if nothing shows up, I go home with out pay because there were no jobs to do. He says he does not have to pay me if there was no work because I am on piece work but he required me to be at work the whole time.

Is this normal and expected for piece work in Canada?

Comment: What is piece work? Is that legally defined, or something your manager just made up?

Comment: Depends on what you contract says.  This is a legal question.

Comment: @MaskedMan yes Piece work is a well known type of work - though it is open to abuse

Comment: This is quite an exploitative practice and I would be surprised if it is legal in Canada. I suggest you consult a lawyer in regards to suing for back pay, and also find a new employer!

Answer (score 14):

Getting work to be done by you is not your responsibility. You should be getting paid for being there and "ready for work". Find another job and fire your boss for not getting you work.